# Solving the convolution equation $U*g=\sin{2x}$ where $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$.

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, transformation, convolution

The problem is as stated in the title but in more detail: find all tempered distributions  $U\in\mathcal{S'(\mathbb{R})}$ that solve the convolution equation given in the title. My approach uses the Fourier transform and a transform table. I know that
$$
\mathfrak{F}(U) \cdot\mathfrak{F}(e^{-|x|})=\mathfrak{F}({\sin(2x)}),
$$
with my table and rearranging I find
$$
\mathfrak{F}(U)=\frac{\pi}{i}\big(\delta(\omega-2)-\delta(\omega+2)\big)
\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}.$$
Then I would find $U$ by computing the inverse transform but I am having difficulties doing that with my table. Is this a good approach or is there a smarter way to do this. You find the table below.

[image]

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{i}\big(\delta(\omega-2)-\delta(\omega+2)\big)
\frac{2}{1+\omega^2}=\frac{\pi}{i}\delta(\omega-2)
\frac{2}{1+2^2}-\frac{\pi}{i}\delta(\omega+2)\frac{2}{1+(-2)^2}$.
Delta-functions impose $\omega=\pm2$ correspondingly.

Comment: Omg, how did I not see this, thanks!